# How to get a footnote to appear in a bookpart title

Tags: lilypond

I have been struggling to get this to work. I have the following code:

```
\language "english"
\book {
    \header {
        title = "Footnote Test"
    }

    \markuplist\table-of-contents
    \bookpart {
        \header {
            title = \markup \line {
    "Tests"
    \footnote "*"
    \concat {
        "*See test appendix in " \with-link #'appendix "Appendix A" } }
        }

        \tocItem tests "Tests"

        \score {
         \header {
           piece = "Test No. 1"
         }
         \new PianoStaff <<
           \new Staff \relative {
               \tocItem tests.testOne "Test No. 1"
             c'4 d e f |
             g a b c \bar "|." |
           }
           \new Staff \relative {
             \clef "bass"
             c4 b a g |
             f e d c |
           }
        >>
      }

      
    }

    \bookpart {
        \header {
            title = "Appendix A: Test Appendix"
        }

        \tocItem appendix "Appendix A: Test Appendix"

        \score {
         \new PianoStaff <<
           \new Staff \relative {
               \key c\minor
             c'4 d ef f |
             g af b c \bar "|." |
           }
           \new Staff \relative {
               \key c\minor
             \clef "bass"
             c4 bf af g |
             f ef d c |
           }
        >>
      }

      
    }
}
```

When I look at the generated PDF, I can see the footnote mark is correctly added to the title:

[image: Asterisk appears on title]

But the footnote is not present at the bottom of the page:

[image: No footnote]

Am I notating this wrong? My code seems to follow the examples shown in the documentation for footnotes, but the footnote does not show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not caused by bookparts, but by the implementation of book titles and score titles. There is no real way around this, but what you can do is either to use a custom markup block instead of the title or to insert a "phantom" footnote directly at the beginning of the bookpart like this
`\markup \footnote \null \concat { "* See test appendix in " \with-link #'appendix "Appendix A" }`. The disadvantage of this is that it will add a little space between the bookpart title and the rest (the space is governed by the markup-markup-spacing).

Of course you could try to integrate such a phantom footnote into the table of contents or the first score, by which you’d be able to get past this small spacing problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot! The extra space isn't too noticeable to me, so this looks good to me. I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Dubl Glad I could help. You probably want a decent space under the title anyway.